# URL Rewriting Help

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to learn Regex & URL Rewriting in PHP. How can I create an .htaccess file which will rewrite (not redirect) any url to `index.php?q={url}`?

For example:

> http://www.example.com/baloon

to

> http://www.example.com/index.php?q=baloon

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?q=$1 [R]
```

...but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewriting ANY url to index.php?q=$1 would result in internal server error as it'd create an endless loop; instead do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is redirecting it. Is there any solution so would stay in its url?

Comment: It shouldn't be redirecting it.

Comment: You didn't add [R] in the rule right? If you did, then it'd redirect (as the other answer said incorrectly).